Is there a local limit theorem for sums of well-behaved non-identically distributed sequences?
Let $X_i$ be a sequence of independent random variables on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ for some $d$. Assume also that $\mathbb{E}||X_i||^3 < a(1+i)^p$ for some positive constants $a,p$. Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$
I know that versions of the central limit theorem, such as Lyupanov's CLT, which if satisfied would imply that $$
D_n(S_n - \mathbb{E}S_n) \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} N(0,I)
$$
for some appropriate sequence of linear transformations $D_n$. I am wondering whether there is a version of the local limit theorem here. I think I can see how to generalize the proof of the ordinary local limit theorem, but I would like to have a citation. I have found some papers which discuss local limit theorems for non-identically distributed random variables that satisfy a uniform bound, but that is not what I am looking for.
